# Unity - Build Android Error : A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build.gradle

this is my first inquiry thread.
I would like to ask for help regarding a problem in Unity. I changed to a new computer and installed Unity after trying to create a project. When testing the build on the PC version,it was able to build normally but when build Android this error came up.

```
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\32.0.0\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-31\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-32\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:extractProguardFiles
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
> Task :launcher:writeReleaseAppMetadata
> Task :launcher:writeReleaseSigningConfigVersions
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareReleaseArtProfile
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJavaResource FAILED
> Task :unityLibrary:writeReleaseAarMetadata
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
35 actionable tasks: 35 executed

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > com.google.common.base.VerifyException (no error message)
```

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-7.2.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"
```

I've tried what people have been looking for but I can't fix it. Can anyone help me solve this build issue for Unity?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you correctly installed everything for android builds ?

Comment: I installed everything through Unity Hub as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to follow this [official guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html)

The error is generated from mandatory tools regarding Android so I would probably go for a clean android environment setup.

Comment: I tried it and everything is still the same.